# Would a sorcerer or a wizard make a better fake warlock?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, roleplaying

I was wanting to build a character that was raised by a warlock before going out on their adventuring days. My question is if the character wants to cast spells like the caretaker warlock, which would be a closer fit?

Comment: Are you playing D&D 5th edition, and also, are you referring to [this D&D 5th edition Caretaker Warlock class](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/251622/Baby-Bestiary-Caretaker-Warlock-5e)?

Comment: yes I am talking about D&D 5th edition but the dm likes the idea I have so far so there might be a bent rule or two I do not know sorry for not mentioning.

Comment: What do "better" or "closer" mean in this context?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Either can work thematically.

Take this description from the Warlock class:

> And sometimes, while poring over tomes of forbidden lore, a brilliant
> but crazed student’s mind is opened to realities beyond the material
> world and to the alien beings that dwell in the outer void.

Poring over tomes? A student of magic? It certainly sounds like a novice Wizard's forbidden studies, compare to this description from the Wizard class:

> They can also learn them from other wizards, from ancient tomes or
> inscriptions, and from ancient creatures (such as the fey) that are
> steeped in magic.

I could imagine a Warlock teacher showing a Wizard student some forbidden tomes and studying together.

Drive is also a common thread between the Warlock and the Sorcerer:

> No one makes a pact with such a mighty patron if he or she doesn’t
> intend to use the power thus gained. Rather, the vast majority of
> warlocks spend their days in active pursuit of their goals, which
> typically means some kind of adventuring.

> People with magical power seething in their veins soon discover that
> the power doesn’t like to stay quiet. A sorcerer’s magic wants to be
> wielded, and it has a tendency to spill out in unpredictable ways if
> it isn’t called on.
>
> Sorcerers often have obscure or quixotic motivations driving them to
> adventure. Some seek a greater understanding of the magical force that
> infuses them, or the answer to the mystery of its origin. Others hope
> to find a way to get rid of it, or to unleash its full potential.

A Warlock teacher may train a Sorcerer student on the nature of their innate power. There could be a lot of life learning about striving towards your goals that a Warlock could impart onto a Sorcerer student.

### Font of Magic can emulate Warlock casting

I think that "in game" Sorcerers more closely match Warlocks. The defining feature of Warlock spell casting is few spells, but powerful spells. A Sorcerer can Font of Magic to transmute their lower level slots to higher level slots.

For example a Warlock 5 has two 3rd level slots (effectively six 3rd level slots for the day). A Sorcerer 5 has two 3rd, three 2nd, and four 1st. By cannibalizing their lower level slots they can generate a total of 17 SP, which can generate three more third level slots - giving them effectively five third level slots (and one first level) for the day. This is very similar to a Warlock's six slots.

A Wizard would not be able to emulate this, so I think that a Sorcerer is a closer match. Someone who was born as a Sorcerer but trained by a Warlock would probably think in this way.

Comment: What do you mean by "effectively six 3rd level slots for the day"?

Comment: @FerventHippo a warlock regains spell slots on a short rest. But I'm not sure why this doesn't theoretically give you 72 3rd level slots (just take 24 short rests per day!).

Comment: @FerventHippo: Sounds like they're assuming 2 short rests per adventuring day, perhaps from some guideline or rule of thumb?   (And they didn't mention Wizard Arcane Recovery, which as a 6th-level Wizard can recover one extra 3rd-level slot per day, not every short rest.)  A Bloodwell Vial to recover extra sorcery points on a short rest could help to manufacture another top-level spell slot.  And of course if you ever cast a spell that doesn't benefit from being upcast, just cast it at 1st or 2nd instead of burning a 3rd-level slot.

Comment: @PeterCordes This is from p 84 DMG “In general, over the course of a full adventuring day, the party will likely need to take two short rests, about one- third and two-thirds of the way through the day.”